# Proportionally scaling div block and image + setting stopping point

Tags: html, css

**The First Part:**

I'm trying to code a layout featuring a div with some text on the left, a tall picture on the right, and a 50% high colored bar div set to the bottom.

The div and the image must scale proportionately. The text won't scale, but must remain positioned correctly at all times.

I've succeeded for the most part, but am having trouble when it comes to the responsiveness. How can I make the colored bar div scale in proportion with the image?

**The Second Part:**

The other challenge I'm having is setting a "stop point" for responsivity. The goal for this stop point would be to have the layout remain fixed (no more scaling down) until the mobile breakpoint is reached. In other words, I want the image and div to be able to scale up indefinitely at larger resolutions, but to only scale down until this stopping point is reached.

The person I'm making this for does not want the text layout to change *at all* until the mobile breakpoint is reached. As a result, I cannot preserve the design's proportions at lower, pre-mobile resolutions (example: 800-900 px width). This is because the text winds up overlapping with the image or div bar after they get to a certain size/position.

**Here's a mock-up of what I'm aiming for:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL8oN.jpg

Here's a fiddle with the code that I have now which does the opposite of what I want but it shows all the elements currently present. 
http://jsfiddle.net/0cf5n6mc/2/

```
.home4 {
position:relative;
height: 765px;
background-color: #FFF;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
}


.feature4text {
position:absolute;
color: red;
left: 10%;
width: 300px; 
top:20px;
}

.orangesm {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
height:100%;
height: 514px;
}


#feat4assets {
  float:right;
  position: relative;
}

 #orangebar {
background-color: #F78B5C;
width: 100%;
height: 382px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
}


.photo-or { 
    height:100%; 
    width: 100%; 
}
.photo-or img { max-height:100%; 
    max-width:100%; 
    width:auto; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    position: relative;
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into CSS media queries?

Comment: Yeah, I have but one media query for the whole site @768px. Do you think I need to add a media query for every common breakpoint to get the functionality I'm after?

Comment: You should only need one depending on well you get your layout to scale.

Comment: That's the problem I'm having, I can only think to make it function the way I want with many different media queries rather than just using one. So I was wondering if there's a way to code it so that it scales the way the image shows, without resorting to different media queries. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: are you open to changing the html structure?

Comment: Oh, yeah! Completely. I'm at a point where I'm willing to change anything just to make it work! :)

Comment: Well you could do this for larger than 767px. http://jsfiddle.net/3kbr8j7r/1/  Then style it in the media query for small screens.  I'm out of time for today.